# raspberry pi live streaming with nginx not playing

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, nginx-location

I am working on a project for which I have to stream live video from raspberry pi camera module in a network. For the purpose I am using nginx server and [picam software](https://github.com/iizukanao/picam) but I am having hard time with it. I added the path to the directory in nginx.conf file uder the http section like this:

```
    server {
            location /hls/ {
                root /run/shm;
                index index.m3u8 index.html;
        } }
```

then I ran the program I tried to access the live streaming from a browser like http://localhost/index.m3u8 , http://localhost/hls/index.m3u8 but it says, **404 not found.**

I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Verify if is the file index.m3u8 in the target directory.

Comment: Tank you for your reply. Actually I was doing wrong. I had to add above lines of code in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing wrong. I had to add above lines of code in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.`